# What is the "big wooden fork" a reference to?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

When Thor and Korg are at the weapons rack preparing to for Thor's fight against the Grandmaster's champion we have the following scene. In it Korg offers up a "big wooden fork" as a weapon to use but both of them quickly dismiss it.

> *INT. THE ARENA - RECEIVING AREA 40*
>
> *Thor, Korg, and a gaggle of other prisoners/fighters have been led from their cells to a PRE-FIGHT HOLDING AREA.*
>
> *Korg and Thor are by the weapons rack.*
>
> **Korg:** Yuck! There’s Still someone’s hair and blood all over this. Guys, can you clean up the weapons once you finish your fight? Disgusting slobs.
>
> *(then:)* Thor...wanna use a big wooden fork?
>
> **Thor:** No.
>
> **Korg:** Yeah, not really useful unless you’re fighting off three vampires that were huddled together.
>
> <sub>*Thor: Ragnarok* official script</sub>

[image: Korg with the big wooden fork]

[Inverse](https://www.inverse.com/article/38082-thor-ragnarok-easter-egg-what-we-do-in-the-shadows-taika-waititi) and various other sources such as [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MovieDetails/comments/86s7k3/in_thor_ragnarok_korg_offers_a_wooden_fork_as_a/) theorise that this is a reference to *What We Do in the Shadows*. This is because Taika Waititi directs both, plays Korg and one of the vampires in the latter.

However, is there a comment anywhere from Waititi confirming that this is the reference or is this a reference to something else?

Comment: Same question on another stack; https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85307/is-what-we-do-in-the-shadows-referenced-in-thor-ragnarok

Comment: @Valorum Saw that but that just points to theories rather than anyone confirming it.

Comment: Indeed. The answer is a copy-paste job on various articles that mention it.

Comment: I saw an interview somewhere with helmsworth and waititi saying in the weapons rack scene they were just talking nonsense for a long time, improvising and having fun. The crew was laughing too. 95% of it was cut but a tiny snippet was left in. It was not scripted. Sorry I can't remember where i saw this.

Comment: @JamesfromNZ - It's mentioned in the commentary. The parts about the hammer pulling Thor were scripted. The rest of the sequence was ad-libbed by the actors.

Answer (score 14):

You are looking into it too much. According to the director, that scene was largely ad-libbed.

> **Taika Waititi:** And once we got to set and saw all these ridiculous weapons that the art department had made *[...]* we just basically started improvising, ad-libing, and started making fun of all these weapons.
> <sub>[Good One - Why Thor: Ragnorok Is So Damn Funny](https://headgum.com/good-one-a-podcast-about-jokes/why-thor-ragnorok-is-so-damn-funny)</sub>

<sup>*(quote starts at 7:17)*</sup>

Waititi goes on to explain that that scene had multiple takes that were 10+ minutes long, and that afterwards they edited it all down.

In fact, a lot of *Thor: Ragnarok* was created in this almost flippant and care free manner. Earlier in the same interview, Waititi said:

> Thats how my sets usually work. It's gotta be fun and a lot of music and lightness. Its also a very creative space where mistakes and dumb ideas are encouraged. Because I think from dumb ideas is usually that's where great mistakes and great jokes come from.
>
> *[...]*
>
> We didn't really do much rehearsal either. All we did was talk about scenes. And as the film was being written and rewritten, the writer, Eric Pearson... I was also like planning out the jokes and things that I... I would just write down a list of things I thought might be good to have in the scene, but I didn't bother trying to put it in the script because I knew it would have to go through five different people to be approved. And often people don't understand the humor or how a good a joke could be until they see it.
> <sub>[Good One - Why Thor: Ragnorok Is So Damn Funny](https://headgum.com/good-one-a-podcast-about-jokes/why-thor-ragnorok-is-so-damn-funny)</sub>

<sup>*(edited for readability)*</sup>

As for the joke itself, in legend, vampires can heal from most injuries fairly quickly. One of the few known ways to actually kill a vampire than, is to drive a wooden stake through its heart. Therefore, if you have three vampires huddled together, the wooden fork would be an effective weapon.

Comment: In my experience, directorial choices in a film with this kind of budget are very rarely (if ever) chosen without deep thought

Comment: @Valorum Is there any evidence that this **was** a directorial choice, and not something that was in the screenplay already?

Comment: I got the impression that Korg was comic relief, from being a failed revolutionary to thinking he killed his best friend.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - In that case, the question is why the *writer* put it in.

Comment: @Valorum Because it's inherently funny considering Thor has been lamenting the loss of his hammer? Sometimes things are just what they are, there's no hidden meaning or reference.